# How to make the instagram actionbar style for android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, instagram

I know how to make the gradient and the logo. But I don`t know how to add all that different borders and how to add the refresh icon (that also has some custom border around it).

Instagram Action Bar:
 [image: http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/1738/instagramactionbar.png]

How is that possible?

Comment: Try 9-patch. Not sure if you can do that in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using a horizontal LinearLayout with 2 children, the left hand column with the logo and the right hand column with the refresh button. You can create a background drawable using the Shape XML:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: My problem is with the strokes. In this actionbar, top, right and left has a 1dip border with a certain color, and in bottom a 2 dip different color.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the provided [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and [ActionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html).  It has hooks for producing basic, as well as complex action bars.